# How can i get a checkbox text inside a <li> tag and show this in another label in jQuery?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net, webforms

What i want to do in the code below is a jQuery code which:

1. If CheckBox1 is selected, the 'selectedCheckBox' label text becomes "Item 1" (same for checkbox2 and 3)
2. (DONE)If 2 or more checkboxes are selected, the 'selectedCheckBox' label text becomes "Group"

> ```
> <asp:Label ID="selectedCheckBox" runat="server" Text="Selected Checkbox Here!"></asp:Label>
>
> ......
>
> <ul>
>     <li>
>         <asp:CheckBox id="CheckBox1 "runat="server" />Item 1</li>
>             <li>
>             <asp:CheckBox id="CheckBox2" runat="server" />Item 2</li>
>         <li>
>             <asp:CheckBox id="CheckBox3" runat="server" />Item 3</li>
> </ul>
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
   <asp:Label ID="selectecCheckBox" CssClass="selectBox" runat="server" Text="Selected Checkbox Here!"></asp:Label>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="Item 1" /></li>
                <li>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" Text="Item 2" /></li>
                <li>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" Text="Item 3" /></li>
            </ul>
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on("change", "input:checkbox", function () {
            if(this.checked)
                SetLabelText(this.nextSibling.innerText);
        });
    });

    function SetLabelText(label) {
        $(".selectBox").text(label);
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <asp:CheckBox id="CheckBox1 "runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="CheckboxClick" Text="Item 1"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <asp:CheckBox id="CheckBox2" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="CheckboxClick" Text="Item 2"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <asp:CheckBox id="CheckBox3" runat="server"  OnCheckedChanged="CheckboxClick" Text="Item 3"/>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In the code behind use something like this:

```
protected void CheckboxClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.selectecCheckBox.Text = ((CheckBox)sender).Checked ? 
        ((CheckBox)sender).Text : 
        this.selectecCheckBox.Text;
}
```